# My HP laptop has 7A-125V powercord (3 prong) but all our wall outlets are 16A-250V (2 prong). I live in the Philippines

Tags: laptop, adapter

I’m so confused! Please bear with me. I’ve been googling since early this morning but nothing has really helped me.

So, I bought a new laptop with 7A-125v powercord (3 prong). Whenever we buy appliances with 3-prong plug, we use a 3-prong to 2-prong 10A-250V adapter. Our wall sockets are 2-prong 16A-250V

But again, the powercord of the laptop is 7A-125V.

Is it ok to use the adapter? Please explain why or why not thanks!

**IMAGES**

Here’s the end of the powercord (It’s a Longwell brand E55349, LP-31M 7A-125V)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymenC.jpg)

Here’s the socket adapter so I can plug it in our wall’s 2-prong 250V socket.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOsbS.jpg)

Here’s the power adapter, texts are super small and color gray (INPUT: 100-240V 50-60Hz. OUTPUT: 19.5V = 2.31A 45 W)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0rMB.png)

**ADDITIONAL INFO:** Laptop is HP notebook 15 f387wm

Comment: Can you post a good picture of the data label on the laptop's power adapter? (Often called the "power brick".) By "good picture", I mean clear enough to read all the fine print. Alternately, please provide the model number of the power adapter. As a third-best option, please provide the model number of the laptop. We need to see the line of text that starts with the word "Input".

Comment: Do **not** plug that adapter in! The USA use 110V (125 max) for wall sockets, but most of the rest of the world uses 220V (250 max). If the adapter is not a "universal" type (and it is not) it will be destroyed and possibly a house fuse blown.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan I updated my post with pictures (texts are too small so I wrote down the details). Also, just wanna clarify, do you need the laptop’s power adapter info? (Coz it’s working fine) Just thought maybe you mean the socket adapter? It’s the one that’s probably not compatible that’s why I asked. Thanks!

Comment: @EugenRieck I updated my post and added pics. I just checked the socket adapter and it’s a universal type. We’ve used it a lot of times since it’s 250V and our outlets are 250V, however I’m concerned because the laptop’s power cord says 125V. Does being a universal socket adapter fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but what you posted is a picture of the details on the WALL PLUG. We need the details on the power adapter - the rectangular-shaped thing that's in between the wall plug and the laptop.

Comment: Do **NOT** plug the adaper! Post a clean picture like [this](https://goo.gl/images/qU359V). We need a picture of the electrical parameters of the 'brick'.

Comment: Chances are the power adapter accepts anything from 100 volts to 240 or 250. (I don't think any 120-only adapters have been made for laptops for at least ten years.) The "125V" embossing on the NEMA-5 (US style) AC plug is simply for the plug itself. In fact no NEMA-5 plug is rated for anything higher; it's simply part of the type specification. I went into great length on this point in my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1407809/348119

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Sorry! I updated the post, the text are really small and color gray so it’s not very clear eventhough the pic is HD. The input says 100-240V.

Comment: Then you're fine. Go ahead and plug in.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Thank you so much! You’ve been a great help AND I actually learned a lot! 5/5 stars for you ⭐️⭐️⭐️⭐️⭐️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in your pictures, the "125V 7A" rating you found is molded onto the plug (the thing at the end of the cord with the two flat prongs and one round prong), and tha rating *only* applies to the plug. That is a "[NEMA 5-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#NEMA_5)" plug (North American common grounded type) and no such plug is rated for more than 125 volts. It can't be, per the type specification.

But what really matters is the input voltage rating on the laptop's "power adapter". (Sometimes called the "AC adapter" or "charger".)

Your power adapter has an input voltage rating of 100 to 250 volts, so it is fine to use with your 240 V supply.

Your cordset will have no problem conducting your 240 volts to the power adapter. The fact that the plug says "125 V" is nearly irrelevant. That is a UL-approved NEMA-5 cordset and as such it has actually been tested to far higher voltages than that. ([This answer](http://superuser.com/a/1407809/348119) of mine to a similar question has more details.)

Reality is that probably millions of travelers from North America plug their laptops into 220 to 240 volt power outlets all around the world, using cordsets exactly like yours with "125V" plugs, and using a socket adapter to adapt to the sockets in the walls wherever they are... and they don't have a problem. You won't either.